# Mac Monterey system update - XAMPP no longer working

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I recently updated to Mac Monterey (12.1), my version of XAMPP (1.0.3) now refuses to open. I have installed a later version of XAMPP which works fine. But all the files from the htdocs folder of the older version are inaccessible.
It is the version where you mount the volume to access the htdocs folder. As I can't mount it I can't access any of my php files.
I assume they still exist somewhere on my Mac ?
Is there any way I can get them back?

Comment: There is something in Mac known as Finder (use the Spotlight search function) . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

That's really something which make me to dislike Apple, actually i loved to work with Mac, because of the linux compatibility and use my mac as dev environment, svn (subversion) is not working anymore (git still works), it would be smart Apple  to take care of their users.

Apple should propose an alternative for XAMPP at least.

For me is a big decrease of quality and interest.

See : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253647606?login=true&page=1

Comment: thanks, very depressing brush off there in your thread from Apple.